# How to add a Onclick function to a Dynamic LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, onclick, linkbutton

I need to add a `Onclick` attribute to my `LinkButton` which I am dynamically generating. How to add it?

Here is the code I came so far and struck with:

```
 foreach(string i in List)//list has more than 50 data's
        {
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.Text = topics;
            link.ID = topics;
            link.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            link.Click += new EventHandler(this.lnk_Click);
            div_ID.Controls.Add(link);
            div_ID.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
         }

public void lnk_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string ctrlId = ((Control)sender).ID;
    GMethod(ctrlId); //handles some function in which i pass the id of the particular lnk button
}
```

I could call this `lnk_Click` from my `LinkButton` on dynamic generation. Its onclick attribute is not getting added to the link button. Please help me out on this guys. I am on urge.

Comment: @laurent ASP.Net, c# 3.5.
I need the code to work in server side.

Comment: During what event are you generating the link buttons? Are you generating them in every post back? Are the items in the List the same with each post back?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the runat="server" attribute, as that will be done automatically. You've assigned the OnClick event handler, so you should be all set there too.

Since you're creating these controls dynamically, make sure that you have code in place to regenerate the LinkButton controls after postback, otherwise your event handler won't fire. Also make sure to assign the same IDs when regenerating it after postback.

Comment: @james.. Thanks but still it isn't working.. When i click the link, the post back takes place but my event[lnk_Click] doesn't get called..
Am i in the right path? Does mt code has any mistake? Pls help me out on this..

Comment: Post some code showing how you're regenerating these controls after postback.

Comment: I have a problem in that too.. i came across , it can be possible only on pre_init function. I am creating the link button dynamically in page load fnction. When i click my dynamically generated link, postback occures but my event doesn't get called and my dynamic links are not getting binding again.. Please help me out on this..

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue that the onClick event of the dynamically created hyperlink was not getting fired. I was making the mistake of placing the code of dynamic creation of hyperlink within "if(!IsPostBack)" and was assigning a random id to the hyperlink every time. So, please try assigning a unique ID and keep the code outside "if(!IsPostBack)". Will work.